# SBS 2003 Routing Faxes To Mailbox

Tags: windows-sbs, fax

I have a client who is having a problem with faxes routing to a mailbox.

The server is SBS 2003, and the faxes are coming in fine to the faxes default folder. After some internet issues last week (probably not related issues), the faxes have stopped being routed into the necessary mailbox.

The event logs are showing:

> Source: Microsoft Fax.
>
> Category: Inbound.
>
> Event ID: 32078.
>
> A successfully received fax was not routed automatically. You can find the fax in the Inbox/Incoming archive folder by its job ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.